# Converting an if-else statement into a switch statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm having trouble turning this program from an if-else statement into a switch statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $@
do
array[$i]=$x
i=$((i+1))
done


# initial state
state=S0


 for((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++))
 do

 if [ $state == S0 ] 
  then
   if [ ${array[$i]} == I0 ]
   then
   state=S1
   output[$i]=O1
   elif [ ${array[$i]} ==  I1 ]
   then
   state=S0
   output[$i]=O0
   fi

  elif [ $state == S1 ]
   then
   if [ ${array[$i]} == I0 ]
    then
    state=S1
    output[$i]=O1
    elif [ ${array[$i]} == I1 ]
     then
    state=S0
    output[$i]=O0
    fi
    fi


    done
    echo "final state="$state
    echo "output="${output[@]}
```

for those who are wondering about script.. this script about finite state machine .. this script has two states I want to convert to case statement so it can be readable and faster especially for big projects not like this one.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with Linux, Emacs or the SQL `CASE` statement. I've removed the extraneous tags.

Answer (score 2):

First, indenting sensibly helps quite a lot for maintaining your code.

One mistake, using single brackets in your if statements -- if the variable on the left-hand side of the comparison is empty, you'll get a syntax error. Use double brackets or use double quotes around the variable. This is important because you're taking input from the user, and you'll never know what you're going to get.

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in "$@"; do
    array[$i]=$x
    ((i++))
done

# initial state
state=S0

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ $state == S0 ]]; then
        if [[ ${array[$i]} == I0 ]]; then
            state=S1
            output[$i]=O1
        elif [[ ${array[$i]} ==  I1 ]]; then
            state=S0
            output[$i]=O0
        fi
    elif [[ $state == S1 ]]; then
        if [[ ${array[$i]} == I0 ]]; then
            state=S1
            output[$i]=O1
        elif [[ ${array[$i]} == I1 ]]; then
            state=S0
            output[$i]=O0
        fi
    fi
done
echo "final state="$state
echo "output="${output[@]}
```

I see that you do exactly the same thing whether state is S0 or S1, so you can remove that part. Also, populating the array variable can be simplified. Leaving:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( "$@" )
state=S0

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${array[$i]} == I0 ]]; then
        state=S1
        output[$i]=O1
    elif [[ ${array[$i]} == I1 ]]; then
        state=S0
        output[$i]=O0
    fi
done

echo "final state: $state"
echo "output: ${output[*]}"
```

Given all this, I don't really see a case statement helping you. But if you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( "$@" )
state=S0   # initial state

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    case ${array[$i]} in
        I0) state=S1; output[$i]=O1 ;;
        I1) state=S0; output[$i]=O0 ;;
    esac
done

echo "final state: $state"
echo "output: ${output[*]}"
```